# Selecting child elements of a fieldset

Tags: javascript, extjs

Let's say I have a sample fieldset as follows :

```
+---| Customer Types | --------------------------+
|                                                |
|   +----------+    +----------+   +---------+   |
|   |  Trader  |    |  Horeca  |   |   SCO   |   |
|   +----------+    +----------+   +---------+   |
|                                                |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

The fieldset has three buttons which are opening a new window. When an employee click one of the buttons, he/she should fill out some necessary fields. After filling out the forms, he/she will click the `submit` button the post records. There is no problem thus far.

What I want to do, an employee fill out the form and click the `submit` button of the opened window, I should disable other buttons to be able to prevent double record.

Here is the questions:

- Is there any method in ExtJS to select child elements of the fieldset?
- Or, do you have any suggestion/sample code to select child elements to disable those buttons that I specified in the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use an `Ext.ComponentQuery`.  This is built in to each component if you use the `down()`, `up()`, and `query()` methods.

To get what you want, do something like this:

```
var buttons = myFieldSet.query('button');
for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++)
    buttons[i].disable();
```

Learn more from the docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

Comment: @dbrin, kevhender thanks for suggestions. One thing I can't resolve until now. How can I keep filled out form button status enable except others?

Comment: Just check that the button you are disabling is not the one you want to stay enabled - e.g. `if (buttons[i].text !== 'Submit') buttons[i].disable()`

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS provides a [ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) class that lets you find any component anywhere in the page. Additionally some of those CQ methods are added for convience to container components, like  the down() method.  Using it you can find your components contained within your fieldset. You can search by xtype, itemId or any arbitrary property of your component.

```
For Components:
    • Ext.getCmp(id)
    • Ext.ComponentQuery.query()
    • up() 
    • down() 
    • nextSibling() 
    • previousSibling()
    • child()
    • previousNode()
plus various find.. Methods

For Elements:
    • Ext.get()
    • Ext.dom.Query() (more on DOM Query http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/content/domquery.html
```